# Get the last data been added over time with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i'm scraping tradingview strategy orders using selenium, i was able to connect to tradingview using my credentials , do all to come to the orders page. to **scrape** orders i have to scroll down all orders, i'm doin it recursively like this.

```html
def checkIfBottomOfViewReached(driver, element):
    return driver.execute_script("if (arguments[0].scrollHeight == arguments[0].offsetHeight + arguments[0].scrollTop) { return true; } else { return false; }", element)


def scrollToElement(driver, element):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)


def printTableDataRecursively(element_table_rows):
    global count
    global table_view
    is_reached = checkIfBottomOfViewReached(driverweb, table_view)
    for el in element_table_rows:
        count = count + 1
        if count == len(element_table_rows) and is_reached  is not True:
            count = 0;
            scrollToElement(driverweb, el)
            rows = driverweb.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.report-content.trades .report-data .table-wrap table tbody")
            element_to_remove = rows[0]
            rows.remove(element_to_remove)
            printTableDataRecursively(rows)
        else:pass
```

after reached the end , i need to get the new orders that is been added to the table so i can use them in my pipeline, is there a way to only get the last item that is been added of over time using python and selenium ?
how can i deal with dynamically added data using selenium ?

[image: orders]

Comment: check if you have an API, seems to be the table is loading data dynamically when you scrolled down.

Comment: Tradingview is quite restrictive on this, there is not any api , and yes the table is loaded dinamically

Comment: If you are sure that all the data is loaded, then you can use the xpath to get the last item.

Comment: Yes but  the data that comes after the scroll i'm unable to get them, do i need to refresh something all the time?

Comment: selenium/python doesn't know what you get previous time. You may have to get all values and compare with values which you already have. If page has system to filter data by date and time then you may try to use it to filter data. You can also try to create xpath with expression which uses `>` or `<`

Comment: after scrolling you have to use again `find` to get all values.

Comment: @furas the problem is that nothing happen when the data is being added dynamically, scroll doesnt happen and the program close with error saying that the element is not found, so i'm not able to get new data , so i cant filter them

Comment: did you try to use `time.sleep(1)` after scroll and before `find` - often JavaScript need more time to download new data add items to HTML.

Comment: yes i tried , same result